# max関数で最大値を求めるときのprint関数の引数がわからない

Tags: python

◆**max**関数で最大値を求めるときの**print**関数の**引数**がわからないのですが、何を当てはめればいいですか？

```
# 三つの整数値から最大値を求める
a = int(input("整数aの値:")
b = int(input("整数bの値:")
c = int(input("整数cの値:")

max = a
if b > max: max = b
if c > max: max = c

print("最大値は{max}です。", max)
```

■ 最終行のprint関数の引数は何を入れたらいいでしょうか？

```
print("最大値は", max, "です。")
```

でもいいのですが、引数は何をいれればいいですか？maxとか入れてみたのですが、思うように動作しません。お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[フォーマット文字列](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)を使いたいのであれば、次のように先頭に `f` を書きます。

```
print(f"最大値は{max}です。")
```

---

質問内容とは関係がありませんが、以下の点も気になったので書いてみます。

- 質問文に書かれているプログラムは `max` 関数を使っていません（`max` 関数で最大値を求めていません）。`max` 関数を使う場合は `max(a, b, c)` などと書いて、この返り値を使います。
- Python には組み込みで [`max` 関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#max)があるので、自分で定義する変数の名前を `max` とするのは避けた方が無難です。思わぬところで名前が上書きされエラーになる場合があります。

Comment: ありがとうございました。無事にインタプリタが通りました。